# Confusion regarding Geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, causality

Suppose we have a **causal** curve and we can cover the causal curve by **convex normal neighborhoods**. We also know that, in convex normal neighborhood there will exist a unique geodesic inside the neighborhood, connecting any two points in the neighborhood.

So, my question is: *Are we making the curve piecewise geodesic?*

If a curve is piecewise geodesic, can we say that the whole curve is a geodesic?

Answer (score 9):

Two points here:

1. Just because the causal curve can be covered by convex normal neighbourhoods doesn't mean that the causal curve follows the geodesic path that exists between any two points in any particular neighbourhood.  As an example, consider an object moving in a circle in Minkowski space with $v < c$, between two times $t_1$ and $t_2$.  Even if I cover this curve with convex normal neighbourhoods, that doesn't mean that it's a geodesic.
2. A "piecewise geodesic" curve, obtained by joining a bunch of geodesics, isn't necessarily a geodesic curve.  This is easy to see in Minkowski space.  If an object moves at $\vec{v}_1$ from $t_0$ to $t_1$, then $\vec{v}_2$ from $t_1$ to $t_2$, and so forth, the resulting curve is piecewise geodesic but is not actually a geodesic unless $\vec{v}_1 = \vec{v}_2 = ...$.

Comment: @SekhSokal:  You're welcome!  If you found this answer useful, please "accept" it by clicking on the check-mark icon near the top left of the answer.  That said, you should probably wait 24 hours or so to do so, in case any better answers are posted (you can only "accept" one answer to your question.)

Comment: also: The second point is equivalent, in Eucildean geometry, to "a piecewise-straight line is not necessarily stright", which should be rather intuitive

Comment: @Toffomat:  If you look at the edit history that's actually the original example I used there.  :-)  I switched to one in Minkowski space mainly to avoid the possible counterargument that spacetime manifolds are different from spatial manifolds — though in the end I think that both of these arguments hold equally well regardless of whether the metric is positive definite.